# Fourier Series and Fourier Transform confusion.

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

I dont understand the following paragraph after the proof. In particular, how does that theorem above give us that the Fourier transform maps $L^2$ onto $l^2$? all that theorem says  is that this set is an orthonormal basis of $L^2$. And how do we get Parsevals, and convergence? 
I'm also very confused about how a function $f(x)$ becomes a function whose input is integers.

Could anyone explain the above, or provide a good source where i can read about this?

[image: Folland's Real analysis, page 248] In

Comment: Whenever you have an orthonormal basis $\{ e_n \}$ in a Hilbert space, meaning that the closed linear span of the basis is all of the space, then you automatically get convergence in norm of $f = \sum_{n}(f,e_n)e_n$ and Parseval's identity $\|f\|=\sum_{n}|(f,e_n)|^2$ for all $f$ in the Hilbert space. I suspect that was taught earlier in the text.

Comment: you lost a square.